# Как создать разные массивы из списка объектов?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Есть список объектов, как мне из этих разных объектов сформировать нужные для меня массивы, например первые 9 объектов объединить в 1 массив, последующие 7 объектов поместить в другой массив, чтобы не создавать кучу списков из массивов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вставляйте пожалуйста исходные данные кодом, а не скрином

Comment: Хорошо, в будущем исправлюсь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  title: 'some title',
  image: 'some image',
  value: 'some value',
  link: 'some link',
  someField: 'some field',
}

const arr1 = []
const arr2 = []


Object.keys(obj).forEach((key, index) => {
  const value = obj[key]
  if(index < 2) {
    arr1.push({ [key]: value})
  }
  if(index >= 2) {
    arr2.push({ [key]: value})
  }
})

console.log(arr1)
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помог!